# Why does AdvancedFilter deactivate all table header dropdown buttons?

Tags: excel, vba, office365

To save time filtering with multiple criteria, I set up a manual filter using the AdvancedFilter function (see below). It runs fine, however I'm surprised to see that all dropdown buttons disappear from the table header -- to restore them, I have to go into Table Design > Table Style Options > Tick off the 'Header Row' box, then tick it on again.
Any idea why this happens?

```
' Clear any existing filter
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    On Error GoTo 0
    
' Make sure you are outside the table
    Range("A1").Select
 
' Set the dimensions of the variables
    Dim rngDatabase As Range
    Dim rngCriteria As Range

' Define the database and criteria ranges
    Set rngDatabase = Sheet1.Range("Table1[#All]")
    Set rngCriteria = Sheet1.Range("A2:J3")
    
' Filter the database using the criteria
    rngDatabase.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange _
        :=rngCriteria, Unique:=False
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you not add the step you are doing manually to the code?

Comment: If I do, for example with the following code:

```
' Restore table headers
    Range("A7").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").ShowHeaders = False
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").ShowHeaders = True
```

Then the advanced filter criteria disappear, and the whole of the table appears again (no more filtering).

...Which is probably why the header dropdown buttons disappear: you can't use AdvancedFilter and the basic filter at the same time.
I guess this solves my question...
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer: you can't use AdvancedFilter at the same time as the basic filter (accessible through the table header dropdown menus).

Whenever I restore the header buttons, my AdvancedFilter is reset and the whole table appears again. D'uh!

Thanks for the comment, that helped me understand!